# why it is not possible to get output on clicking on items in grid view in android while using Button in adapter code

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, gridview

// using Button in gridview doesnt giving me any output on gridview's item's onclick method

MainActivity class

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ButtonAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "selected" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //getting no input
        }
    });`  

 public class ButtoneAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ButtonAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 81;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }



@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;
        gridView =new View(mContext);
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, null);
        Button city = (Button) gridView.findViewById(R.id.basic);

        return gridView;
}
```

Just because of using button I am unable to get output from clicking on gridview's item;

Comment: If you want to use get separate click listener for button and gridview you have to use custom adapter.

Comment: that's custom already i wanna know that if we replace Button widget with ImageView we will get output but when we are using Button then we wont get output on  gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {//toast//});

Comment: Yes thats right. Because If you add button inside GridView the button gets all the attention. Set button's focusable and clickable false to get gridview click. If you want to get both use ViewHolder in your Custom Adapter.